# MediaPlayer server died

Tags: android, android-camera, android-videoview, audioflinger

I'm trying to play mp4 video in loop and i have a problem with two device (on all other devices my code works fine) *Motorola Defy 2.2.1* and *Motorola Atrix 4G 2.3*.

The problem is after one run the media got stuck and I get this error :

```
08-12 17:04:15.031: W/MediaPlayer(4710): info/warning (1, 44)
08-12 17:04:15.031: I/MediaPlayer(4710): Info (1,44)
08-12 17:04:15.031: D/MediaPlayer(4710): getMetadata
08-12 17:04:30.742: W/AudioSystem(4710): AudioFlinger server died!
08-12 17:04:30.742: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(4710): media server died
08-12 17:04:30.742: E/MediaPlayer(4710): error (100, 0)
08-12 17:04:30.742: W/AudioSystem(4710): AudioPolicyService server died!
08-12 17:04:30.750: E/MediaPlayer(4710): Error (100,0)
08-12 17:04:30.750: D/VideoView(4710): Error: 100,0
08-12 17:04:30.750: E/MediaPlayer(4710): stop called in state 0
08-12 17:04:30.750: E/MediaPlayer(4710): error (-38, 0)
08-12 17:04:30.750: W/MediaPlayer(4710): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
08-12 17:04:59.711: D/dalvikvm(4710): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9260 objects / 742128 bytes in 80ms
```

this is my code:

```
protected void prepareVideoView(File video, String clipId) {

    // final Activity currentView = this;
    final VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

    vv.setOnErrorListener(Library_callHandler.getErrorHandler(video));
    vv.setVideoPath(video.getAbsolutePath());
    vv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    vv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            try {
                int counter = 0;
                while (vv.isPlaying() && counter++ < 3) {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread();
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                    }
                }
                if (vv.isPlaying()) {

                    com.vringo.shared.Log
                            .log(com.vringo.shared.Log.LEVEL_INFO,
                                    "VmcRingerActivity onCompletion vv.isPlaying()--> finish()");
                    finishInstance();
                    return;
                }
                vv.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // ResidentService.restoreRinger(currentView);
            }
        }
    });
    vv.start();

    Library_callHandler.track_info("CLIP_RINGTONE", clipId);
    // - tracker.trackEvent(VringoConstants.CAT_CLIPS,
    // VringoConstants.ACT_PLAY_RINGER,
    // String.valueOf(videoClip.getClipId()), 0);
    // - tracker.dispatch();

    // Library_callHandler.info("Ringer video playback started.");
}
```

Comment: Hi Isabella if you have found the solution.Please share.